# How to copy a debian mediawiki installation

Tags: debian, symbolic-link, tar, mediawiki

The MediaWiki installation on Debian uses a file structure all over the system and symbolic links to enable/disable extensions/configs etc. I understand this is because Debian has preferred locations for user-editable vs. "standard" configs/files etc., and is set up for multi-site capabilities etc.

I want to copy a live mediawiki install over to a local "stage" site on a Virtual machine running Debian. I have the "bare bones" mediawiki running, and have even copied over the MySQL Database with success. However the extensions, skins, images etc. are missing.
Since it's a headless server I would like to tarball the files, download them, and extract them to their proper place on the VM - which is non-trivial to do on this system due to the complex/sprawling file heirarchy.

Has anyone done this, and can offer advice, scripts & appropriate `tar` command (preserving symlinks)?
Not sure how to get tar to compress and extract the directories I need with symlinks properly.

The [debian mediawiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/MediaWiki) describes some of the directories and a *bit* of the symlinking (confusingly stating that "**Most** core files from /usr/share/mediawiki are symlinked into this directory"...).

Comment: [How do I get a list of installed files from a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package) might be helpful.

Comment: Indeed, that is helpful (although exhaustive, containing hundreds and hundreds of lines!). Thanks!